# MVC dynamically loaded modal form working locally but not working on production

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have modal popup bootstrap its content being loaded by ajax to get a partial view .
It has Ajax.BeginForm and validate, save form successfully in local IIS(v.10) or developing environment but in production server (IIS v.8) its only validate the form and never post the form.
No client side error appears in console in chrome 
**What went wrong?**

***layout***

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

***web.config***

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

---

***partial view***

```
@{
        Layout = null;
    }
    @model SMSAPI.Models.Group

    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Groups</h5>
                </div>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Groups",
                      new AjaxOptions
                      {
                          OnSuccess = "AfterAjaxSuccess();",
                          OnFailure = "AfterAjaxFailure();",
                          HttpMethod = "POST"
                      },
                      new { id = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Group_ID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Created_By)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Created_Date)
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="control-group ">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Group_Code)
                            <span class="help">"use chars, numbers, special chars"</span>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Group_Code, new { @class = "form-control " })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Group_Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group ">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Group_Name)
                            <span class="help">e.g. "Managers, Supervisors and Salespersons etc"</span>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Group_Name, new { @class = "form-control " })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Group_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-ef btn-ef-3 btn-ef-3c" id="myModalSaveBtn" guid="" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-lightred btn-ef btn-ef-4 btn-ef-4c" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you check if all the css and js are loading from production? Also check if there is any script error on the console.

Comment: all css, js files are loaded, no error in client side

Comment: Then one more thing to check - if any popup is blocked on the browser.

Comment: popup appears and its form validation is working, but never post form data.. no error happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**
**I figured out why**

The production server did not allow http get and post for web service
Just add

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

***within***

```
 <system.web>
```